# How to add Force Quit Icon in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: icons, ubuntu-12.04

I have just migrated from Ubuntu 10.04 to 12.04. As most of the UI elements have been changed I don't know to add Force quit icon, which is needed for most of the not responding applications.
So, how to add force quit icon in ubuntu 12.04?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the terminal, run these commands:

1. ```
   cat > ~/.local/share/applications/Force_Quit.desktop <<EOF
   [Desktop Entry]
   Name=Force Quit
   Comment=Force Kill an Unresponsive Running Application or Window
   Exec=xkill
   Icon=gnome-panel-force-quit
   Terminal=false
   Type=Application
   StartupNotify=true
   EOF
   ```
2. `nautilus ~/.local/share/applications/`
3. Now in the window that popped up, drag `Force_Quit.desktop` to the Unity launcher.

*`xkill` will now be invoked every time you click on the new launcher icon.*

[image: [Force Quit on the Launcher]]

<sup><sub>Source: [How To Add A Force Quit Icon To The Unity Launcher - Ubuntu 11.10/12.04](https://web.archive.org/web/20180528074630/http://www.upubuntu.com/2012/02/how-to-add-force-quit-icon-to-unity.html)</sub></sup>

Comment: Why these much steps needed in Ubuntu 12.04. I did with a single click in 10.04. Is there any easy way for that? - @Deltik

Comment: I created a new file in the name of ForceQuit.desktop. But I couldn't open the file to copy the provided content. It says, "There was an error launching the application."

Comment: I opened the file via gedit and pasted the content. Finally, I got the Force Quit functionality.

Comment: **I edited the answer to make it easier to follow.**

Comment: Your previous solution can be followed by even those who don't have the internet connection to access http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=MHRX6KEV - @Deltik

Comment: @arulappan **I edited the answer to eliminate link rotting of the essential steps.**  Also, in response to your first comment, Ubuntu and GNOME 3 sacrificed the formerly established customizability of GNOME 2.  [(My rant)](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1883114)

Answer (score 1):

A far easier way is to simply head over to your keyboard shortcuts, add a custom one to let's say F11, name it something like "Kill non-responsive windows" and with the command used xkill.